# Modifying nested structs in c#

Tags: c#, struct

Can someone tell me why the commented line of code (one before last) does not compile? Isn't it the same as the line following it?

```
public struct OtherStruct
{
    public int PublicProperty { get; set; }
    public int PublicField;

    public OtherStruct(int propertyValue, int fieldValue)
        : this()
    {
        PublicProperty = propertyValue;
        PublicField = fieldValue;
    }

    public int GetProperty()
    {
        return PublicProperty;
    }
    public void SetProperty(int value)
    {
        PublicProperty = value;
    }
}

public struct SomeStruct
{
    public OtherStruct OtherStruct { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeStruct a = new SomeStruct();
        //a.OtherStruct.PublicProperty++;
        a.OtherStruct.SetProperty(a.OtherStruct.GetProperty() + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SomeStruct.OtherStruct` is a property, returning a value - it's not a variable. This line:

```
a.OtherStruct.PublicProperty++;
```

is like calling:

```
a.get_OtherStruct().PublicProperty++;
```

Because the expression `a.get_OtherStruct()` is a *value* rather than a *variable*, it's a bit like doing this:

```
OtherStruct tmp = a.get_OtherStruct();
tmp.PublicProperty++;
```

Changing the value of `PublicProperty` in the *copy* of `OtherStruct` returned by the property isn't going to change the original value at all. That's almost certainly not your intention. The C# designers foresaw this sort of problem, and managed to prohibit it in many situations.

Note that if `OtherStruct` were a reference type (a class) instead, then it would be the *reference* that was copied, not the values within it... so changing `tmp.PublicProperty` *would* make a difference. See my [article on reference and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more information.

Btw, mutable structs like this are generally a really bad idea. They cause all kinds of problems, and hard-to-predict code.

EDIT: In response to your "answer", the two lines *aren't* the same: the `a.OtherStruct` property expression isn't the target of an assignment operator or a compound assignment operator.

You can argue that you'd like C# to be defined in a way which would allow this (although I'd still disagree) but the compiler *is* implementing the specification correctly. See section 10.7.2 of the C# 3.0 spec for more details.

Comment: I think it may be clearer if you used an example that showed the difference between value types and reference types.

Comment: @Jeff: I've added a paragraph and a link... hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: Yup, I think that makes a big difference. It's a good explanation, btw, just think subject can be confusing so every little helps. Cheers.

Comment: Please see the next answer - I could not fit it into a comment.

Comment: I see what you're saying. In the OtherStruct example, a.OtherStruct gets laid on the stack, which yields a copy. While in the SomeStruct example, the set of the PublicProperty is going directly to the variable and not to a copy.
 That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not using a comment, I don't think it will fit. 
Jon, this is not an actual implementation, I'm just trying to get a deeper understanding of structs, so no worries about me implementing mutable structs :)

Anyway, I'm not sure you are correct. Consider this code, it's almost the same as first example:

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public int PublicProperty { get; set; }
    public int PublicField;

    public SomeStruct(int propertyValue, int fieldValue)
        : this()
    {
        PublicProperty = propertyValue;
        PublicField = fieldValue;
    }

    public int GetProperty()
    {
        return PublicProperty;
    }
    public void SetProperty(int value)
    {
        PublicProperty = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeStruct a = new SomeStruct(1, 1);
        a.PublicProperty++;
        a.SetProperty(a.GetProperty()+1);
    }
}
```

Now, looking at the msil using ildasm, gives me the following for the Main method:

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed

{

```
.entrypoint

// Code size       45 (0x2d)

.maxstack  3

.locals init ([0] valuetype ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct a)

IL_0000:  nop

IL_0001:  ldloca.s   a

IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1

IL_0004:  ldc.i4.1

IL_0005:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct::.ctor(int32,
                                                                         int32)
IL_000a:  nop

IL_000b:  ldloca.s   a

IL_000d:  dup

IL_000e:  call       instance int32
```

ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct::get_PublicProperty()

```
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.1

IL_0014:  add

IL_0015:  call       instance void
```

ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct::set_PublicProperty(int32)

```
IL_001a:  nop

IL_001b:  ldloca.s   a

IL_001d:  ldloca.s   a

IL_001f:  call       instance int32 ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct::GetProperty()

IL_0024:  ldc.i4.1

IL_0025:  add

IL_0026:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication1.SomeStruct::SetProperty(int32)

IL_002b:  nop

IL_002c:  ret
```

}

I apologize for the terrible formatting, I'm not sure how to make it look normal. Anyway, hopefully, you can see that the last 2 lines of code in the main method are actually identical.

Therefore, I would argue that, from the previous post, this line:

```
a.OtherStruct.PublicProperty++;
```

Is actually identical to the line after it:

```
 a.OtherStruct.SetProperty(a.OtherStruct.GetProperty() + 1);
```

And therefore it seems to me that the first line does not compile simply because the compiler does not support it, not because it is not legal.

What do you think?

Comment: This should have been edited into the question instead of added as an answer... anyway, I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: OK, will remember for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Structures should not expose field-like read-write properties absent a good reason for doing so.  Instead, they should simply expose fields directly.  *Most of the "problems" that are attributed to "mutable structs" are really problems with structs that expose read-write properties.*  In your example, if you had simply made member `OtherStruct` of type `SomeStruct` be a field rather than a propertie (i.e. lose the `{ get; set; }` then there would be no problems with the nested struct access.

Note also that the one "problem" people have with "mutable structs" which isn't associated with mutating `this` (something which field-like properties do) stems from fact that in the following code:

```
  someStructType myThing = MyDataSupplier.GetSomeData();
  myThing.someField = something;
```

the change to `myThing` won't be percolate back to `MyDataSupplier` absent some code like:

```
  MyCollection[whatever] = myThing;
```

My reaction would be "Naturally.  Knowing that `someStructType` is a struct with field `someField` is sufficient to know that `myThing.someField` may be altered without affecting anything else in the universe."  By contrast, if one were to substitute `myClassType`, and `myClassType` had a mutable member (whether field or property), the above code "might" cleanly alter the data in `MyDataSupplier`, or it might not, and such modification might or might not corrupt other aspects of the system state.  Effectively, the complaint is that one would have predictable behavior which would not always match what one wants to do, as opposed to having semantics which depend upon many things, including in some cases other consumers of `MyDataSupplier`.  Note also that if `someStructType` exposed a read-write property rather than a field, one would have to examine the code associated with that property to determine whether it might affect things outside the structure instance upon which it is invoked.